# Constructing a string from pyowm weather data

Tags: python, string, text, weather

Attempting a basic weather program using pyowm.

```
import pyowm

owm = pyowm.OWM('MY_API_KEY')
mgr = owm.weather_manager()
observation = mgr.weather_at_place('Birmingham,uk')
w = observation.weather
temperature = w.temperature('celsius')

print(temperature)
```

I was hoping that this would output in a simple way, but alas, no luck. This is the current output

```
{'temp': 3.75, 'temp_max': 4.44, 'temp_min': 2.0, 'feels_like': 0.22, 'temp_kf': None}
```

Is there any easy way to build a string from this data? Something like
`Temp = 3.75` `Feels_Like = 0.22`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your output is a dictionary type. You can build a formatted string based on those values:

```
temperature={'temp': 3.75, 'temp_max': 4.44, 'temp_min': 2.0, 'feels_like': 0.22, 'temp_kf': None}
outputString="Temp = {0} Feels_Like = {1}".format(temperature["temp"],temperature["feels_like"])
print(outputString)
```

Output:

```
'Temp = 3.75 Feels_Like = 0.22'
```

Comment: Thanks mate, this worked. Don't know if this is too much to ask but could you explain why/how it works? I'm not familliar with dictionaries in python.

Comment: Basically dictionaries are made of unique key value pairs(their elements are enclosed between {}). In your case the keys are strings, and their values are float numbers. You can access the elements like: dictValue=dict[key]. In the end, the format method is called to replace the two string placeholders wih the dictionary values.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `fstring` to generate the required string from the given output as:

```
temperature = {'temp': 3.75, 'temp_max': 4.44, 'temp_min': 2.0, 'feels_like': 0.22, 'temp_kf': None}
str1 = f"Temp = {temperature['temp']}" 
str2 = f"Feels_Like = {temperature['feels_like']}"
print(str1, str2)
```

Output: `Temp = 3.75 Feels_Like = 0.22`

If you just need to `print` as the given output string, you can do it in one line as:

```
print(f"Temp = {temperature['temp']} Feels_Like = {temperature['feels_like']}")
```